# De-vectorizing array manipulation in Julia

Tags: python, arrays, logic, julia, vectorization

This question is an extension from [one of my previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64920864/optimizing-an-array-calculation-with-numpy) on optimizing an array calculation in Python. The answer for my given problem was given via @tomjn as

```
tot_list = np.where((X == 1) | (Y == 1) | (Z == 1),np.random.random(),1).sum(axis=1)
```

Now, I want to write this in Julia. The above can easily be translated as

```
tot_list = ifelse.((X.==1).|(Y.==1).|(Z.==1),rand(Float64),1)
```

Note that X, Y, and Z are logical matrices. When I run my code in Julia, the above works fine. However, it is terribly slow. I am trying to de-vectorize the above, and I get

```
tot_list = similar(X)
for j in 1:length(tot_list)
    tot_list[j] = ifelse((X[j]==1)|(Y[j]==1)|(Z[j]==1),rand(Float64),1)
end
```

However, the resulting code does not actually yield the same result as the vectorized, inefficient version. I am not able to give an example, because the difference is only apparent for very large inputs, but I am positive that there is a big difference between the two portions of Julia code written above. What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't the two tot_lists be the same?

EDIT: The discrepancy might be due to the calculation I am trying to do *after* I perform this calculation. Before I run the above, I define

```
variable_tot = zeros(Float64,1,8*N_state)
```

After I run the tot_list calculation given above, I then run

```
variable_tot=variable_tot+reshape(tot_list,:,length(tot_list))
```

Would this have something to do with my issue?

Comment: Are `X`, `Y`, and `Z` non-`const` global variables? If so, just wrapping your code in a function will help a ton.

Comment: @OscarSmith They are not global variables. I define a function, and have defined them specifically within this function as subsets of a larger matrix. To be specific, I call a large nxm logical matrix, extract certain columns and call them R1 and R2, set X=R1, Y=R1|R2, and Z=R1&R2.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps try this code:

```
((x) -> x ? rand() : 1.0).(X .| Y .| Z)
```

Note that it is critical for performance for a Julia function to be type-stable. Since `rand()` is returning `Float64` the alternative `1` value also needs to be `Float64` - and hence `1.0` is used instead of `1`.

Performance testing - 5ms for 1'000'000 elements matrices on my machine:

```
X = rand(Bool, 1000, 1000)
Y = rand(Bool, 1000, 1000)
Z = rand(Bool, 1000, 1000)

julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime ((x) -> x ? rand() : 1.0).($X .| $Y .| $Z)
  5.615 ms (2 allocations: 7.63 MiB)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it gives me the same result as my vectorized code. Give me a minute; let me edit my question to include more information about my specific calculation. EDIT: Ok, my question has been edited to include a little more of my code. It might be due to how I'm manipulating tot_list after I do the main calculation....

Comment: Just a quick note; I changed my code to tot_list = ifelse.((X.==1).|(Y.==1).|(Z.==1),rand(Float64),1.0) based on your answer, and I immediately got a speedup. Thank you for your suggestion. However, I am still very curious as to why there is still a difference between this snippet of code and your cleaner version.

Comment: Part of the reason is that `ifelse` evaluates both inputs. This means you are calling `rand` way more than necessary.

Comment: It might also be because you do `X == 1` instead of just `X`.

Answer (score 1):

What about (edited with `ifelse` which is faster for me)

```
R = rand(size(X)...)  # generate all the random values at once
C = @. X | Y | Z      # the condition
@. ifelse(C, R, 1.0)  # the output
```

which generates all the random values (even those you won't use, but it does it in one swoop, which is I think faster than looping over `rand()`), allocates the condition `C`, and then applies `ifelse`.

Edit 2, adding a comparison: this solution allocates more but is a bit faster for me:

```
julia> @btime ((x) -> x ? rand() : 1.0).($X .| $Y .| $Z) ;
  5.598 ms (2 allocations: 7.63 MiB)

julia> @btime (R = rand(size($X)...) ; C = @. $X | $Y | $Z ; @. ifelse(C, R, 1.0)) ;
  3.739 ms (8 allocations: 15.38 MiB)
```

Comment: No, sorry, it's the same issue that I had with my de-vectorized version. I think there's a slight difference and it might be due to how I'm doing my summation (see edited question), but I'm not sure.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do after. Your summation only appears in the python code. If I understand correctly, `X`, `Y`, and `Z` are 2D arrays, and `tot_list` is a 1D row array that sums the "1 or rand" 2D array over the first dimension? So you'd need to do `tot_list = sum(O, dims=1)` where `O = @. ifelse(C, R, 1.0)`. Not sure what your `N_state` value is or why you want to reshape `tot_list`? Also, if you initialize it to `zero`s , adding it will do nothing. And if you need to reshape a column vector to a row vector or vice versa, I'd do `transpose(x)` or `x'` or `permutedims(x)`.